# JSON data print in (element).html in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, codeigniter

What I am actually trying to achieve, I am doing query in `codeigniter`. Data is coming properly but, I am quite unable to show it to HTML element. Please check json output in firebug console and code as below-

**JSON Output:**

```
{"founduser":
    {
      "user_id":"2",
      "name":"Altab Hossen",
      "email":"ilove@gmail.com",
      "password":"",
      "employee_id":"0122",
      "nric_number":"K90031G",
      "is_user_active":"1"}
}
```

**Ajax Code**

```
var userid = $("#userid").val();                    
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: base_url+"checkuser/"+userid,
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

Now: alert(data); returning me `Object Object`.
I want to do show only name (Altab Hossen) in div element: `$('.showusername').html(data.name);`

How Can I achieve?

Comment: try alert(data.founduser.name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.showusername').html(data.founduser.name);
```

and if you want to display a json as a string while debugging, you need to use `JSON.stringify()` like,

```
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data.founduser.name
```

to access the object

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot about `founduser`. Try

```
$('.showusername').html(data.founduser.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting, sorry I was using my mobile when posting the answer ; )